# Why is networkx's girvan newman algorithm only returning 2 communities?

Tags: python, networkx, graphml

I am  using the networkx library, more specifically the girvan_newman algorithm from nextworkx.algorithms.community.centrality on a data set of about 1200 vertices each with 1-10 edges between them.  When I run the below code I only see two communities

```
ret = girvan_newman(G)
tuple(sorted(c) for c in next(ret))
```

I want to see it broken down further.  I then tried

```
import itertools
limited=itertools.takewhile(lambda c: len(c) <= 20, ret)
for communities in limited:
  print(tuple(sorted(c) for c in communities))
```

but the output is empty and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I also can't figure out how to access the lists of communities to put into a dataframe, not just print them.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [Girvan-Newman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girvan%E2%80%93Newman_algorithm)

Comment: @Galen I've read the page.  what exactly are you trying to show me?  does this only remove one edge at a time and I have to just run it inside a loop?  the examples in the documentation show multiple communities with the code on the bottom, but for me it isnt returning anything?

Comment: Sorry, I should have expressed that I was putting the link there for passer-by-readers that are unfamiliar with what the algorithm is supposed to do.

Comment: @Galen oh my mistake.  Thank you

Comment: Can you show (or at least describe) the output of `tuple(sorted(c) for c in next(ret))`?  The reason the output of the second block of code is empty appears to be because `ret` is "exhausted" - you looped through all of its values in creating the tuple, and now it's empty.